# Android: как передать current location в AsyncTask

Tags: android, строки, android-asynctask, геолокация, synchronized

Приложение погода. Через asyntask отправляю запрос в openweathermap и в postexecute начинаю биндить результат в ui, с заранее определенным  городом все проходит на ура, добавил функцию запроса геолокации пользователя и сохраняю его в статическое поле, но asynctask выполняется до запроса геолокации, как сделать чтоб чтобы async task работал после запроса данных геолокации

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        getLastLocation()

        weatherTask().execute()

    }

public class Common {

    public static final String APP_ID = "a6g096e9c7045fffc90db97209788939";

    public static Location current_location = null;


}
```

методом сохраняя координаты в common.current_location

```
                mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    val location: Location? = task.result
                    if (location == null) {
                        requestNewLocationData()
                    } else {
                        Common.current_location.latitude = location.latitude
                        Common.current_location.longitude = location.longitude
                        Toast.makeText(this, "${location.latitude}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//                        latTextView.text = location.laлtitude.toString()
//                        lonTextView.text = location.longitude.toString()
                    }
                }
```

может как то возможно передать координаты в asynctask

```
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String? {
            return try{
                URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${Common.current_location.latitude}&lon=${Common.current_location.latitude}&appid=${Common.APP_ID}").readText(
                    Charsets.UTF_8
                )
            }catch (e: Exception){
                null
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вызывайте `weatherTask().execute()` в `OnCompleteListener`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую